# Best IDE for GTKmm+3

Tags: linux, c++, ide

I'm looking for the best IDE for GTKmm3 application development code word suggestions.  I took a look around Geany, but I have doubts about the quality in GTK 3 (maybe if I use GTK 2 I don't doubt it anymore). I also had time to see opinions about it is better to use a plain text editor. But I'm afraid this will make the troubleshooting time longer than productivity time and poor of features. I've used Gnome Builder and it's only good for creating templates not for word suggestions when writing code. **Which IDE is good for GTKmm+3? Eclipse, Geany, Netbeans, Code::Blocks, Anjuta, Geany, or maybe  is there a better IDE?** Then what plugins should I install afterwards?
I will use it together with Gnome Builder.

**The main point I look for :** just for auto complete or word suggestion (code from the GTKMM+3 framework) when using the IDE.
I can use gnome builder for compiling if your suggested IDE haven't built in compiler(even though it's impossible)

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! [What's "best" is always subjective](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/157/185): *one man's trash is another man's treasure.* Better describe what would make this software *fitting best for you* – which then enables us to give fitting recommendations. See [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for more hints. Also note we don't do [software comparison](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/185).

Comment: Ok, this is subjective. But at least I'm looking for the one that best meets the main points I'm looking for

Comment: I still don't understand. I will read it again tomorrow

Comment: That edit already helped! Of course, the better you describe your requirements, the better potential answers can match them. Best luck!